# Why blocking I/O is happening?

Tags: asynchronous, nio, blocking, nonblocking

I often heard about `asynchronous I/O`, which is non-blocking if there's nothing to I/O.

My question is, when we do some `blocking operation`, I don't see any logic ***in my code*** that block the execution. So, who cause the blocking? The operating system?

So if we want `non-blocking operation`, do we ***have to*** wait for the OS to provide the support? Or can we implement a `non-blocking` version over the `blocking` version?

Comment: "I often heard about asynchronous I/O, which is non-blocking if there's nothing to I/O": this statement is very confused. There are three different things: blocking I/O, non-blocking I/O, and asynchronous I/O. Only the first of these blocks.

Comment: @EJP To be honest, I am not quite sure about the distinction between non-blocking and asynchronous. Thanks for bringing it up. I am sure async I/O is non-blocking. Is there some non-blocking I/O that's not async?

Answer (score 1):

Every code in same process(thread) is blocking as usual.
After one code done, do the next line.
You don't have to declare the `blocking` type.

On the other hand, if you want to `non-blocking` some code.
You must run in other process(thread) to do that.

Comment: coding is kind of art, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'd like to keep this open for some more time.